# ios core data to AZ indexed tableview

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to show the values of my core data model to an A-Z indexed table based on the first letter on my attributes (similar to the iOS address book app). The "Favorites" entity of my core data model has 2 attributes: username and status. I want to display only the usernames with `status = accepted` to the A-Z indexed table.
Here is my code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favorites" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSString *status = @"accepted";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@",status];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Create the sort descriptors array.
NSSortDescriptor *usernameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"username" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:usernameDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"username" cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Now when I'm trying to access the section name I get (null)

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",[[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name]);
     return [[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
 }
```

Also I thing that with that way I will get the the name and not the first char in order to display it as a section title.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the sectionsInfo object properly:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> info = 
    [fetchedResultsController sections][section];
return [info name];
```

However, this will give you a heading for each unique name, probably not want you want. Instead, you have to give your entity a *transient property* e.g. `NSString *sectionIdentifier` and write a getter for it that returns the first letter of the username attribute.

If want an index from A-Z running down on the right edge of the table view you additionally have to implement:

`sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and
`tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`.

If you still get `null` for your titles, maybe they are not set or persisted in your entity? Maybe you got zero results? Maybe your fetchedResultsController is `nil`? There are a number of flaws in your data model, so this seems quite possible.

- Your entity name `Favorites` is plural. That is not logical, you should name it `Favorite` as one instance only describes one favourite.
- The status is a string which is also very inefficient. Instead, you should use a number and apply some enum scheme.
- The username is a property of `Favorite`. That seems also very messy because presumably, you also have a `User` entity which has a `username` attribute. You should use a relationship to model this.

Comment: thank you for your answer, still if i put your code inside the titleForHeaderProperty  and NSLog the [info name] i get null value..

Comment: I added some more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

use  `NSFetchedResultsController's` [`sectionIndexTitles`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchedResultsController/sectionIndexTitles) function to get array of first char